# setState array based on dynamic checkbox and text input

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, user-interface

I am working on developing a UI in react js where i am generating a dynamic table from the data i get from the API, on the left side i have check boxes and each check box have a particular input of type text, which are dynamically generated as stated. What i want to archive is  as soon as user check box is checked i need to generate an object which has following 4 fileds `isChecked` (to check wheather the check box is checked or not), `module_id` (if checked than i need to get the module id), `isUpdated` (this is for tracking any changes made on the specific input text, if not it should be zero  ), `discount_price` (if `isUpdated` is true than i need this value). these things i am trying to achieve by `setState` in react js.

The necessity for the above defined object is for handling the data in 
back-end. Based on the conditions i ll be writing the queries, i hope i am clear with my statement problem.

I have initialized the object state in constructor of the class component, i have binded the handleChange method in with both inputs of checkbox and text, but i am getting error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined`, i want to know the best approach of handling such dynamic forms.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {moduleData: [], modules : [] }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

this is my handleChange function

```
handleChange(event) {
    const key = event.target.dataset.moduleindex;
    const modId =  event.target.dataset.moduleid;
    const inputKeyType = event.target.type;
    var is_updated = 1;
    if(inputKeyType == 'checkbox'){
      var inputChecked = !this.state.modules[key].checked;
      if (!this.state.modules[key].checked == false) {
        is_updated = 0;
      }
    } else {
      var inputChecked = true;
      is_updated = 1;
    }

    this.setState({
      modules: {
        ...this.state.modules,
        [key]: {
          ["isChecked"]: inputChecked,
          ["module_id"]: modId,
          ["isUpdated"]: is_updated,
          ["discount_price"]: event.target.value,
        }
      }
    });

  }
```

and this the table which is generated dynamically

```
const moduleRow =  modules.map((module, index) => (
    <tr key={module.id.toString()}>
              <th scope="row" width="" className='text-center' >
                <Input type="checkbox"
                className="checkbox"
                name="module_id"
                data-moduleindex = {index}
                data-moduleid = {module.id}
                checked={
                  this.state.modules[index]
                    ? this.state.modules[index].checked
                    : ""
                }
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </th>

              <td>
                {module.module_name}
              </td>

              <td>
                {module.module_short_code}
              </td>

              <td>
                {module.limits}
              </td>

              <td>
                { module.subscriptionInterval === 'monthly' ?  module.monthly_price  : module.annual_price }
              </td>

              <td>
                <Input
                type="text"
                name="discount_price"
                data-moduleindex = {index}
                id = {module.id}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={
                  this.state.modules[index]
                    ? this.state.modules[index].discount_price
                    : ""
                }
                />
              </td>

              <td>
                {this.getStatus(module.status)}
              </td>

            </tr>
          ));
```

finally i want to get the array of objects like this

```
[
  0:{"isChecked":true, "module_id":2, "isUpdated" : 1, "discount_price": 5 },
  1:{"isChecked":false, "module_id":3, "isUpdated" : 1, "discount_price": 5 },
  2: {"isChecked":true, "module_id":8, "isUpdated" : 0, "discount_price": "" }
  ]
```

can this be achieved or am i missing some thing? pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here;

```
if(inputKeyType == 'checkbox'){
  var inputChecked = !this.state.modules[key].checked;
  if (!this.state.modules[key].checked == false) {
    is_updated = 0;
  }
}
```

`this.state.modules` will be an empty array on initialisation. You are using `checked` rather than `isChecked`. All checkboxes start as false so something like;

```
if(inputKeyType === 'checkbox'){
  var inputChecked = this.state.modules[key] ? !this.state.modules[key].isChecked : true
  if (inputChecked === false) {
    is_updated = 0;
  }
} else {
  var inputChecked = true;
  is_updated = 1;
}
```

`this.state.modules` also starts as an array, and you end up assigning it as an object in `setState`. So in your constructor I would make modules initialised as an empty object

And also in the input type need to do this

```
 <Input type="checkbox"
                className="checkbox"
                name="module_id"
                data-moduleindex = {index}
                data-moduleid = {module.id}
                checked={
                  this.state.modules[index]
                    ? this.state.modules[index].isChecked
                    : ""
                }
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it really helped me to solve some of the issue, now i am able to get the exact data, will except your answer once i solve it.